# How to configure a VPN on Linux GUI given just a configuration file?

Tags: 20.04, vpn, gui

I received one configuration file from my university technical staff to configure an OpenVPN connection. According to the staff, I must open the connection manually in command line through the following command

> openvpn --config configuration_file.conf

However, I must keep a terminal opened with that command running (probably through screen I can less disturbance). However, can I use the VPN connection GUI from Ubuntu to configure that VPN using the information found in the configuration file? how to do that?

The contents of the configuration file are below:

```
#############################################
# Sample client-side OpenVPN 2.0 config file.
# for connecting to multi-client server. 
##############################################

#tls-cipher "DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=0"

# Specify that we are a client and that we
# will be pulling certain config file directives
# from the server.
client

dev tun
proto udp

# The hostname/IP and port of the server.
remote <ip-adress> <port>


# host name of the OpenVPN server.  Very useful
# on machines which are not permanently connected
# to the internet such as laptops.
resolv-retry infinite

# Most clients don't need to bind to
# a specific local port number.
nobind

# Try to preserve some state across restarts.
persist-key
persist-tun

comp-lzo



# Certificate Authority
<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
BLABLABLA
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>

# Username/Password authentication is used on the server
auth-user-pass

# Verify server certificate by checking
# that the certicate has the nsCertType
# field set to "server".  This is an
# important precaution to protect against
# a potential attack discussed here:
#  http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm
#
# To use this feature, you will need to generate
# your server certificates with the nsCertType
# field set to "server".  The build-key-server
# script in the easy-rsa folder will do this.
ns-cert-type server

# Set log file verbosity.
verb 3
```

Comment: You can use the NetworkManager GUI to do this, though you may need to install plugins to do so, and without knowing which of the possible desktop environments you're using, it's impossible to tell you how to go about it.

Comment: @Kurankat I am using Ubuntu GNOME

Comment: I just want to know which kind of information I should put there. Can I, for example, realize which kind of authentication type my vpn asks just from the configuration file?

Comment: I use KDE, so I can't tell you how to do this in GNOME. That said, in KDE I can go to network settings, add new network, then choose to import a VPN config. Rather than adding your credentials to the file, you should be able to get GNOME keyring to remember them for you. I have both `openvpn` and `network-manager-openvpn` installed on my machine.

Comment: You may need to install `network-manager-openvpn-gnome`as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are able to import a VPN configuration using GNOME's network management GUI.  Just click "**Import from file...**" under **Settings -> Network -> Add VPN**

[image: Screenshot of Settings]